# How to set private key to CmsSigner in .net 4.7

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have a program with .net 4.7 and we used a CMSSign class, it fail when try to compute sign, actually we convert the class from .Net Core and private property missed, the below code is from .net core

```
CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(xcert);
signer.PrivateKey = privateKey; // missed in .net 4.7
```

and here full code from from 4.7 and it's not working as expected :

```
 Pkcs11InteropFactories factories = new Pkcs11InteropFactories();
        using (var lib = factories.Pkcs11LibraryFactory.LoadPkcs11Library(factories, dllPath, AppType.MultiThreaded))
        {
            ISlot slot = lib.GetSlotList(SlotsType.WithTokenPresent).First();
            if (slot is null)
            {
                return "No slots found";
            }

            ITokenInfo tokenInfo = slot.GetTokenInfo();
            using (ISession session = slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadOnly))
            {
                session.Login(CKU.CKU_USER, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456"));
                List<IObjectAttribute> certificateSearchAttributes = new List<IObjectAttribute>
                {
                    session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE),
                    session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true),
                    session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CERTIFICATE_TYPE, CKC.CKC_X_509)
                };
                IObjectHandle certificate = session.FindAllObjects(certificateSearchAttributes).FirstOrDefault();
                if (certificate is null)
                {
                    return "Certificate not found";
                }

                var attributeValues = session.GetAttributeValue(certificate, new List<CKA>
                {
                    CKA.CKA_VALUE
                });


                var searchAttribute = new List<IObjectAttribute>()
                {
                    session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY),
                    session.Factories.ObjectAttributeFactory.Create(CKA.CKA_KEY_TYPE, CKK.CKK_RSA)
                };

                IObjectHandle privateKeyHandler = session.FindAllObjects(searchAttribute).FirstOrDefault();

                var xcert = new X509Certificate2(attributeValues[0].GetValueAsByteArray());
                RSA privateKey = new TokenRSA(xcert, session, slot, privateKeyHandler);


                string serializedDocument = "Text To sign";
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedDocument);
                ContentInfo content = new ContentInfo(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.7.5"), data);
                SignedCms cms = new SignedCms(content, detached: true);
                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(xcert);
                EssCertIDv2 bouncyCertificate = new EssCertIDv2(new Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.X509.AlgorithmIdentifier(new DerObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47")), HashBytes(xcert.RawData));
                SigningCertificateV2 signerCertificateV2 = new SigningCertificateV2(new EssCertIDv2[1] { bouncyCertificate });
                signer.DigestAlgorithm = new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1");
                signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new Pkcs9SigningTime(DateTime.UtcNow));
                signer.SignedAttributes.Add(new AsnEncodedData(new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47"), signerCertificateV2.GetEncoded()));
                cms.ComputeSignature(signer);
                byte[] output = cms.Encode();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(output, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework version of CmsSigner only works when the certificate object is already coupled to its private key (`cert.HasPrivateKey` is true).

On .NET Framework 4.7 that pretty well requires putting the cert and private key together in a PFX, or having already had them associated in a cert that's in a cert store.

If `privateKey` is already just assigned something like `cert.GetRSAPrivateKey()` then you shouldn't need to assign signer.PrivateKey.

Comment: cert.HasPrivateKey = false ;  and cert.GetRSAPrivateKey() return null :(

Comment: i have object RSA privateKey and object X509Certificate2 cert, do you know how to set privateKey to sign, i try CopyWithPrivateKey but get an exception Private key export is not supported

Comment: Add full code hope you can help me
+bartonjs

Comment: @msm2020 If you can figure out how to open your private key via RSACng / CngKey.Open, then you can use `CopyWithPrivateKey`.  If you can't, then what you want is only available on .NET Core (it was a new feature to support "external" private keys).

Comment: so the above code can't working with .net 4.7 or any higher only .Net core :'(
then how i can call .net core Dll or class from .net 4.7, any suggest to help me 
@bartonjs